# problem running sencha codes in eclipseEE

Tags: sencha-touch

How to run sencha touch codes in phonegap framework using ECLIPSE IDE?
We are facing problems as where to paste the codes and where to post the sencha libs..also we cant figure out how to run the code on the android emulator?do we need to run with a web server? 
currently we have pasted the sencha code in assets folder(www subdirectory) and the sencha libraries in libs directory.But wen we run it in the emulator, it just displays the HTML part and not the sencha UI??!!! 
plz reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to make sure that the HTML has included the correct links to the lib and app resources, in the head of the document.

See http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Sencha_Touch_Hello_World for an example of how to set up the Sencha Touch directories and outer HTML.